# CSS Table Styles - Trying to give more space

Tags: html, css, coding-style

Good Day Everyone,

I'm writing a Wordpress Plugin with CSS and jQuery and PHP.

I have the below table, I'm trying to modify the CSS but it doesn't seem to apply properly. My table basically looks like:

```
|--------------------------------------------|
| Username:                                  |
|--------------------------------------------|
|                                            |
|--------------------------------------------|
|Email                                       |
|--------------------------------------------|
||------------------------------------------||
||Year  |   Month    |     Day              ||
||      |            |                      ||
||------------------------------------------||
|--------------------------------------------|
```

It's really all condensed, I'm trying to give it more space more something like:

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|                                            |
| Username:                                  |
|                                            |
|--------------------------------------------|
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|--------------------------------------------|
|                                            |
|Email                                       |
|                                            |
|--------------------------------------------|
||------------------------------------------||
||Year  |   Month    |     Day              ||
||      |            |                      ||
||------------------------------------------||
|--------------------------------------------|
```

When I do the following CSS:

```
.registration table td {
    border: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

It changes the tables "INSIDE" the other Table, but it doesn't change the Main Table can anyone help me where I'm wrong because I need the styling to be better than that...

```
<form id="registration" action="" method="POST">
    <table class="registration_table">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="reg_tablerow_1">
                <div class="regpage_text required" id="order_1">
                    <label for="username">Username: *</label>
                    <br>
                    <input id="username" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" type="text">
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Year</td>
                                <td>Month</td>
                                <td>Day</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="year" id="year">
                                        <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
                                        <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="month" id="month">
                                        <option value="1" selected="selected">January</option>
                                        <option value="2">February</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="day" id="day">
                                        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**EDIT UPDATE**

Brett answer was the closest right answer, but if you look closely to my HTML there is some TD missing which causes the padding-bottom not to work.

I had to review my scripting and all my html to realize that a bad copy / paste made me copy some information without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have a class registration but an id registration on your form.

add a class to the form or modify css to

```
#registration table td {
border: 0;
padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I will look into this Brett as soon as I can. Will come back to you shortly

Comment: I'll mark your answer as right Brett cause you were right in my example I made a mistake about calling the class instead of the ID... But I also found out that in my scripting I was missing my <td>'s properly marked everywhere... Your answer was right though - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Vertical center use this :

```
vertical-align: middle; Or bottom Or Top
```

For horizontal center use this line :

```
text-align: center; Or left Or right
```

For height issue use :

```
height: 00px; & line-height: 00px;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about ... If I could I would down vote your answer.